# Text wrapping not working when creating Child Element of StackPanel in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, text

I am trying to implement a `TextBlock` in C# which is added to a `StackPanel` by C# code, I managed to get the `TextBlock` added but I am not able to make it wrap around text, I have tried the following but it still cuts off text when it's out of length and doesn't wrap it onto a new line.

```
           sp1.Children.Add(
                 new TextBlock() {
                    Text = longStringNeedingWrap,
                    Width = 590,
                    TextWrapping = Wrap,
                    Height = double.NaN,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10, 3, 10, 0),
            });
```

I have made sure that I implement the `TextWrapping = Wrap` by adding `public TextWrapping Wrap { get; set; }`, my code shows no errors and runs fine but it still doesn't wrap the text.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`TextWrapping = Wrap,`

to

`TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,`